# How to configure avahi in VirtuabBox NAT

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, virtualbox, avahi

I have a VBox Linux guest in NAT networking mode.
Both host (also a Linux system) and guest have the avahi-daemon service running. Is there a way to configure the service in the guest so that it does not interfere with the host (localhost port 5353)? 
It works fine in bridge mode, but I can't figure out what rules to add I in NAT mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That makes no sense...
When you use NAT for the guest it shares the hosts IP-address. It therefore conflicts with network services (like AVAHI) on the host if the guest offers those same services to the LAN.

In most cases you can re-configure the service to run on another non-standard port.

However a service like AVAHI is always expected (by all other AVAHI clients) to run on the same port. It is one of those few services that you can't really put on another port if you want other devices to be able to use it. (DHCP, DNS, TFTP are a couple of others that you normally can't reconfigure for the same reason.)

So put your guest in bridge or don't run AVAHI on the host. There is no other way around it.